# Can't use Get Method in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm not good enough at english and PHP. So I have a question: How to get result by 'GET' request?
i have an url like this:

```
laporanpemesanancetak.php?TANGGAL_PERIODE1=2016-05-01&TANGGAL_PERIODE2=2016-05-23
```

and my GET method like:

```
if (isset($_GET["$TANGGAL_PERIODE1"])) {
    $TANGGAL_PERIODE1 = $_GET["TANGGAL_PERIODE1"];
    $TANGGAL_PERIODE2 = $_GET["TANGGAL_PERIODE2"];

    $query = mysql_query("select p.PURCHASE_ORDER_PEMESANAN,p.TANGGAL_PEMESANAN,s.NAMA_SUPPLIER,i.NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU,p.JUMLAH_PEMESANAN,i.SATUAN,k.NAMA_KARYAWAN
                                        from pemesanan p,supplier s,inventori i,karyawan k 
                                        where p.NPWP_SUPPLIER = s.NPWP_SUPPLIER and p.ID_BAHAN_BAKU = i.ID_BAHAN_BAKU and p.NIP_KARYAWAN = k.NIP_KARYAWAN and p.TANGGAL_PEMESANAN between '$TANGGAL_PERIODE1' and '$TANGGAL_PERIODE2' order by p.PURCHASE_ORDER_PEMESANAN");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,$row["PURCHASE_ORDER_PEMESANAN"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,$row["TANGGAL_PEMESANAN"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,$row["NAMA_SUPPLIER"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,$row["NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,$row["JUMLAH_PEMESANAN"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,$row["SATUAN"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(27,8,$row["NAMA_KARYAWAN"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Ln();
}
}
```

and the result is show nothing, i've tried using

```
if (isset($_GET["$TANGGAL_PERIODE1"])&&$_GET["$TANGGAL_PERIODE2"])
```

but the result is same, i've tried my sql query into mysql and it works.

Can someone help me please? it would be great :)

Comment: Learn what a `$` means in PHP. That will help you solve this problem very quickly.

Comment: remove `$` from  `$_GET["$TANGGAL_PERIODE1"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET["$TANGGAL_PERIODE1"]`

Note the `$` in the key.  This will try to evaluate the variable `$TANGAL_PERIODE1` rather than look a key of the $_GET array named `TANGAL_PERIODE1`

Be sure to not ignore E_NOTICE and E_WARNING messages when developing.  These are important clues, this would generate a notice of an undefined variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer.. i'll study hard from this on :) @Devon